# Undefined variable $router

Tags: php, lumen

I'm trying to host my website; it works fine on my VS code but when I hosted it and run it gave me this error.

I'm using php - lumen framework.

[28-Nov-2023 13:12:17 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined variable $router in /home/xx/portfolio/routes/web.php on line 16

[28-Nov-2023 13:12:17 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get() on null in /home/xx/portfolio/routes/web.php:16

I'm new to php overall and to the framework itself.

this is my code on web.php

```
<?php

/** @var \Laravel\Lumen\Routing\Router $router */

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It is a breeze. Simply tell Lumen the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the Closure to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/
$router = app('router');
$router->get('/', function () use ($router) {
    return view('portfolio');
});

$router->get('/blog', function () {
    return view('blog');
});
```

Comment: `Call to undefined function app()` or `Undefined variable $router`...which message are you getting? Or are you seeing both? It wasn't 100% clear - your title says one thing and the description says something else. Try to be clear and specific so we don't have to assume/guess, or spend time to sit and work it out. Remember we can't see your screen or access your environment. See also [ask]

Comment: both

[28-Nov-2023 13:12:17 UTC] PHP Warning:  Undefined variable $router in /home/xx/portfolio/routes/web.php on line 16
[28-Nov-2023 13:12:17 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get() on null in /home/xx/portfolio/routes/web.php:16

Comment: Anyway, it _sounds_ like maybe you didn't upload all the files needed for the framework when you deployed your site, or that a necessary `include` / autoload function is failing somewhere. Make sure you've fully enabled error logging (a public server shouldn't be showing errors directly in the browser) and check for any such warnings.

Comment: And pleaase [edit] your question if you have updates - don't bury them in the comments - these are only for very brief suggestions or requests for clarification. Stackoverflow isn't like a traditional discussion forum.

Comment: So now you say you're not actually getting `Call to undefined function app()` at all then??? Or are there really _three_ errors?

Comment: It's a simple website not that complicated so I'm pretty sure it was fully uploaded; do you think I have check on a certain file?

Comment: it's just 2 lines of errors I posted them and updated my question, I'm sorry if I confused you.

Comment: Did you miss to include the autoloader?

Comment: I checked and if you mean this line (require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';)
it's included in the bootstrap/app.php

Comment: Something is off here, I don't see how $router _could_ be undefined, after `$router = app('router');` - even if that function did not return anything, $router should still at least be _set_ now, with NULL as value. You should verify what the file on your server actually contains. I don't think line breaks converted during an FTP upload could be the case here, but maybe you got some other "invisible" characters in there, that make it basically "ignore" the `$router = app('router');` line.

Comment: Do you really need this `use ($router)` in `$router->get('/', function () use ($router) {`?